# Constructor input validation using while loop not working

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, equals, composition

I am trying to initialize the instance fields of the class Animal using validation checks I provided in the constructor. It seems to work if I enter the correct value--for e.g tiger--when calling the constructor but does not work if i enter the same value after entering an incorrect value. For some reason it does not seem to exit the while loop. I am using composition to test if the fields value was entered correctly.

public class Animal {
        private String type;

```
    public Animal(String type) {
    enter code here

        if ((type.equals("cheetah")) || (type.equals("tiger")) || (type.equals("Snake")) || (type.equals("lion"))) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        else  {
            Scanner animaltype = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("This animal has either left the jungle or is not present in the jungle. Please enter another value.");
            type = animaltype.next();
            while ((!type.trim().equals("cheetah") || (!type.trim().equals("tiger")) || (!type.trim().equals("Snake")) || (!type.trim().equals("lion"))))
                     {
                if (type.equals("kangaroo")) {
                    System.out.println("Kangaroos have left the jungle. Please enter another value");
                    type = animaltype.next();
                }
               else if ((!type.trim().equals("kangaroo")) || (!type.trim().equals("cheetah")) || (!type.trim().equals("tiger")) || (!type.trim().equals("Snake")) || (!type.trim().equals("lion"))) {
                    System.out.println("This animal is not present in the Jungle. Please enter another value");
                    type = animaltype.next();
                }


            }
            this.type = type;
        }
        }



    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner animaltype = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Store the type of animal that is in the jungle");

        String rt = animaltype.next();
        Animal animal = new Animal(rt);
        Jungle jungle = new Jungle(animal);

        System.out.println(jungle.getAnimal().getType());
    }
}

public class Jungle {
    private Animal animal;


    public Jungle(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;

    }

    public Animal getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your `while` loop is incorrect. It says that if `type` is not equal to at least one of the strings, then keep going. Well, `type` can't be equal to more than one of those strings, so the while loop will continue forever. This phenomenon happens because you are using `or` and need to be using `and` operator. You need to replace the condition with `(!type.trim().equals("cheetah") && (!type.trim().equals("tiger")) && (!type.trim().equals("Snake")) && (!type.trim().equals("lion")))`, or alternatively `!(type.trim().equals("cheetah) || type.trim().equals("tiger") || type.trim().equals("Snake") || type.trim().equals("lion"))`. Both say that if `type` is equal to any of the strings, then get out of the `while` loop.

PS: `trim()` is not needed since `Scanner`'s `next` method returns the next token, which basically means the next word, so `type` will already be trimmed.